# Creating Backup before rooting

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, backup

I am planning to root my android ICS phone. How can I create a backup of android OS before rooting it?

Will creating a backup brick my phone?

Comment: See this post asked by @Izzy entitled http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices The question contains links to other very useful posts that may interest you.

Comment: is there a danger of bricking the device while rooting it?

Comment: @TechGeek Rooting a phone can potentially be risky if you are not familiar with the phone and the rooting process. When rooting, you should carefully follow the instructions for your specific phone and operating system (OS) version. If done properly, you should not have any problems. Should any problems arise and you brick your phone (completely locks up), you could try returning it to the store, but more likely your only recourse will be to turn to the internet and specifically the XDA Forums for help.

Comment: @TechGeek There will always be disadvantages - dangers as you call it, but generally people will tell you the advantages to rooting far outweigh any disadvantage. However only root if you really need too !!

Comment: If you made a backup before, and have the current stock image at hand for flashing, in the worst case you've have to factory-reset and re-flash, then restore your backup. It's unlikely that any rooting method woould brick your phone so complete that you cannot at least boot-up your phone to recovery/fastboot/whatever and flash the stock image back.